# Deep Freeze any type

Tags: javascript

Is this enough to deep freeze any kind of type?

```
function freeze(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    Reflect.ownKeys(obj).forEach((key) => {freeze(obj[key])});
  }

  return Object.freeze(obj);
}
```

Comment: Functions are also objects, but `typeof` will return `function` :\

Comment: Could you elaborate about why you want to freeze an entire object graph?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, JavaScript still doesn't have a way to do that. For example, `Date` instances cannot be frozen:

```js
var dt = new Date(2016, 11, 27);
console.log(dt.getDate()); // 27
Object.freeze(dt);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
console.log(dt.getDate()); // 28
```

Some other issues/notes:

- [As Matías said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343535/deep-freeze-any-type#comment69889121_41343535), functions are objects, but `typeof` will give you `"function"` for them.
- `Reflect.ownKeys` only gives you the object's **own** keys, not the keys for their prototypes. So depending on your definition of "deep freeze," you may need to copy inherited properties to the object before freezing it.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this cause problems with scalar types, if someone does `Object.freeze(<constructor>)`? Just wondering.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Good point, the `Object.freeze` at the end should probably be in the `if` block as well, but `Object.freeze` [is a no-op for non-objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.freeze), so it's not a problem. Re freezing a constructor, I don't think that would be a problem (but I suspect the user doesn't want to freeze functions anyway).

Comment: I would also add that it's a very heavy operation. It hurts performance. After all is a recursive object properties' re-definition. Some years ago I developed some JS library and I was freezing objects, and finally I realized that, since JS is a dynamically-typed language, it's a good friend of duck typing.

Comment: can be improved? how?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I'm not seeing the relationship between freezing and duck typing...? Freezing is a defensive mechanism to prevent modification. (Whether it works for that as currently implemented in JavaScript is another whole topic... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well it's not 100% related, but it's how people thinks that JavaScript should work and actually how it works. When you want to be too defensive in JavaScript, based on my experience (in addition to being developer I also perform some courses, one is about JavaScript), I've found many professionals that use some features like `Object.freeze` to mimic how strongly-typed, compiled languages work (i.e. C#, Java...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Clearly `Object.freeze`  is a good tool to create immutable objects, but it's not to make an entire object graph immutable, because there should be something wrong in your design if you go this route, or simply you don't want to deal with the dynamic nature of JavaScript.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I just haven't seen people using `freeze` for that purpose, I guess. I can see them doing it, but really, if you want to mimic a hardcoded property list, `Object.preventExtensions` would be closer in my view. Sure, it doesn't prevent people changing the type of a property, but it allows them to continue setting the *values* of properties. Anyway, we're well afield of the question here... :-)

Comment: That's why we're using comments :D Yeah, obviously `Object.preventExtensions` would be enough. I believe you already know what's my point. If I'm not mistaken, OP's question is an XY problem. We should know why OP wants to freeze an entire object graph...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I would like to ensure that these objects used for testing purposes are not modified (keep immutability)

Comment: @Martin Uhm, it seems like you want to use `Object.freeze` like a contract: don't try to set these objects' properties.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that is the idea a "contract" to easy test:
```
const fn = (parm) => {parm.foo='bang'};

const a = {foo: 'foo'};
const b = {foo: 'foo'};
fn(a)
expect(a).toEqual(b); // <- fail


const a = {foo: 'foo'};
try {
  fn(freeze(a))
} catch (e) {
// `fn` wrong doing with `a`
}
```